# Hidden the view when animated, State property in different Struct

Tags: xcode, model-view-controller, view, state, swiftui

I'm have my rectangle in my view that when pressed it expand in order to show more detail to the user.

Now on the bottom part I have to display other stuff ..once the user press the rectangle it need to overlay this data.

as you can see on my picture once I press the rectangle the view expand but the text("CIAO") still visible.

[image: before press on rectangle][image: After press]

```
struct DetailViewNew: View {
    var dm : DataManager
    let general: GenAirportModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            ZStack {
                GeometryReader { geo in

                 VStack(alignment:.leading){
                    self.airport
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .offset(y: geo.size.height/6.3)
                    RectanglePersonal(general: self.general)


                 }
                 .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height/2.5)
                 .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("BlueW"), Color("DARK")]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing).shadow(radius: 2))
                 .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                Spacer()


                }
                Text("CIAO")

            }
            Spacer()
        }

    }
```

my idea was using a @State once the user press the rectangle set the the view to hidden()
but the issue is, I'm detecting if the user press the rectangle in another struct RectanglePersonal (using the state isExpanded)

```
struct RectanglePersonal: View {
    let general: GenAirportModel
    @State private var isExpanded = false

    var body : some View {
        GeometryReader { g in
            ZStack(alignment:.leading) {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.clear)
                    .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("BlueW"), Color("DARK")]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
//                    .blur(radius: 20)

                    .cornerRadius(20)
//                    .foregroundColor(Color("BlueW"))

                    .shadow(color: .white, radius: 10)
                    .padding(.horizontal,5)
                    .frame(width: g.size.width,
                           height: self.isExpanded ? g.size.height*2 : g.size.height/1.3)
                    .offset(y: self.isExpanded ? g.size.height : g.size.height/2.5)
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5))
                VStack(alignment:.leading) {
                    Text("METAR:")
                        .bold()
                    Text(self.general.metarData.raw_text)
                        .lineLimit(self.isExpanded ? nil : 2)
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5))
                    Text("TAF:")
                        .bold()
                    Text(self.general.tafData.raw_text)
                        .lineLimit(self.isExpanded ? nil : 2)
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5))
                }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .offset(y: self.isExpanded ? g.size.height : g.size.height/2.5)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5))
            }.padding()
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.isExpanded.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

how can I detect from the struct RectanglePersonal the value of @isExpanded? and read it from my view DetailViewNew? in order to hidden the text "CIAO"

Comment: use @Binding ;)

Comment: did you ever checked how sheets (aka modal views) work in SwiftUI? Don't try to reinvent it ...